# Select latest available SQL entry state

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, group-by

Consider this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE cash_depot_state 
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATE,
    amount REAL,
    cash_depot_id INTEGER
);
    
INSERT INTO cash_depot_state (date, amount, cash_depot_id) 
VALUES (DATE('2022-03-02'), 382489, 5);
INSERT INTO cash_depot_state (date, amount, cash_depot_id) 
VALUES (DATE('2022-03-03'), 750, 2);
INSERT INTO cash_depot_state (date, amount, cash_depot_id) 
VALUES (DATE('2022-03-04'), 750, 3);
INSERT INTO cash_depot_state (date, amount, cash_depot_id) 
VALUES (DATE('2022-03-05'), 0, 5);
```

For an array of dates I need to select sum of all cash depots' actual amounts:

1. 2022-03-01 - no data available - expect 0
2. 2022-03-02 - cash depot #5 has changed it's value to 382489 - expect 382489
3. 2022-03-03 - cash depot #2 has changed it's value to 750 - expect 382489 + 750
4. 2022-03-03 - cash depot #3 has changed it's value to 750 - expect 382489 + 750 + 750
5. 2022-03-04 - cash depot #5 has changed it's value to 0 - expect 0 + 750 + 750

My best attempt: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/94ad0d/1

But I can't figure out how to pick winner of a subgroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the latest amount per cash depot as the record that has row number 1, when you divvy up records by `cash_depot_id`, and order them descending by `date`:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    cash_depot_id,
    date,
    amount,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cash_depot_id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
FROM
    cash_depot_state
```

This will highlight the latest data from your table - all the relevant rows will have `rn = 1`:

| id | cash_depot_id | date | amount | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-03-03 | 750.0 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-03-04 | 750.0 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | 2022-03-05 | 0.0 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 2022-03-02 | 382489.0 | 2 |

Now you can use a `WHERE` clause to filter records to a certain date, e.g. `WHERE data <= '2022-03-05'`:

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount) sum_amount
FROM
    (
        SELECT amount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cash_depot_id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
        FROM   cash_depot_state 
        WHERE  date <= '2022-03-05'
    ) latest
WHERE
    rn = 1;
```

will return `1500`.

---

A more traditional way to solve this would be a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount) sum_amount
FROM
    cash_depot_state s
WHERE
    date = (
        SELECT MAX(date)
        FROM   cash_depot_state
        WHERE  date <= '2022-03-05' AND cash_depot_id = s.cash_depot_id
    )
```

or a join against a materialized sub-query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount) sum_amount
FROM
    cash_depot_state s
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT   MAX(date) date, cash_depot_id
        FROM     cash_depot_state
        WHERE    date <= '2022-03-05' 
        GROUP BY cash_depot_id
    ) latest ON latest.cash_depot_id = s.cash_depot_id AND latest.date = s.date
```

In large tables, these are potentially faster than the `ROW_NUMBER()` variant. YMMV, take measurements.

---

An index that covers `date`, `cash_depot_id`, and `amount` helps all shown approaches:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_latest_cash ON cash_depot_state (date DESC, cash_depot_id ASC, amount);
```

---

To run against a CTE that produces a calendar, any of the above can be correlated as a subquery

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(date) AS (
  SELECT '2022-03-01'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date(date, '+1 day') FROM dates WHERE date < DATE('now')
)
SELECT
    date,
    IFNULL(
        (
            -- any of the above approaches with `WHERE date <= dates.date`
        ), 0
    ) balance
FROM
    dates;
```

e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/94ad0d/12

Comment: Many thanks for elaborate examples! Could you please make one, resembling my usage array of dates in sqlfiddle? I can't use 'where' since I need to join with this array

Comment: @NickFarsi Uhhh... I think I've shown you more than enough to go on. You will figure out how to integrate this into your CTE when you give it a little thought.

Comment: @NickFarsi Hint: Run one of the query variants above once per date.

Comment: If by run once per date you mean left join than it does not work because for 2022-03-02 rn would be = 2 and I can no longer use 'WHERE rn = 1'

Comment: @NickFarsi Try a subquery. `WITH RECURSIVE dates(date) AS (...) SELECT date, (SELECT ...) AS amount FROM dates;`

Comment: @NickFarsi Did you get it to run?

Comment: Got a little busy :) I will try today and will update my post with sql fiddle if I succeed

Comment: @NickFarsi If you *really* can't figure it out, I'll post a fiddle update myself. But I'd much rather see you put it together, all the pieces are there.

Comment: Made it!
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/94ad0d/11
Many thanks for your help. Could you please update your post with full solution? Can't make edits

Comment: @NickFarsi Nice, well done! Here's how I would have written it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/94ad0d/12 - of all the options this has the simplest query plan.